# How to reset the text of the closest span object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="file" name="file-7" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
  <label for="file-7">
     <span>This is test</span>
     <strong>Upload photo</strong>
  </label>
</div>
```

I want to clear the text (if any) of the span using jquery. I have written the code:

```
$('#file-7').on('change', function(){
      var spn = $(this).closest('span');
      spn.attr('text','');
});
```

The text is not getting removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: p/s: There's no need to convert a jQuery object again: what you're doing is technically `$($(this).closest('span'))`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's not always the person who commented also the one who downvoted your question, you know...

Comment: @Terry, sorry Sir, I didn't mean you downvoted it. Neither the question was meant for you, else I would have mentioned you in the previous question. The question was in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#file-7').on('change', function(){
      var spn = $(this).closest('.box').find('span');
      spn.text('');
});
```

**Explanation:** You have to find the closest parent element which has the span where you are trying to replace text. Here the parent is `.box` & then find the `span` in it.

2nd mistake you made is `$(spn).attr('text','');`. here there is no need of `$()` & no use of `attr()`. You can do as simple as `spn.text('');`

Working sample for you:

```js
    $('#file-7').on('change', function(){
          var spn = $(this).closest('.box').find('span');
          spn.text('');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input type="file" name="file-7" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
  <label for="file-7">
     <span>This is test</span>
     <strong>Upload photo</strong>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes! There was no need to put that extra "$". I put it by mistake. Thanks for correcting me. I have a question. Does it mean we need to traverse to the parent and then find the object? Can we use `$(this).parent('div').find('span');` as well?

Answer (score 4):

you just need to do that

```
spn.html('');
```

we don't need to write $() with variable

Answer (score 0):

You can replace text with text function in jQuery. And you have a typo error your variable is spn but you are using it as $(spn).

```js
$('#file-7').on('change', function(){
      var spn = $(this).next('label').find('span');
      spn.text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input type="file" name="file-7" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
  <label for="file-7">
     <span>This is test</span>
     <strong>Upload photo</strong>
  </label>
</div>
```